# rake db:migrate not pushing migrations through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning Rails using a tutorial, working in Nitrous.io and have modified my migration files to create the relationships between the models.  It is a simple time tracker app.  An example of one of the modified migration files is this:

```
class CreateWorks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :works do |t|
      t.integer :project_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.datetime :datetimeperformed
      t.decimal :hours, precision: 5, scale: 2
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The project id, user id, datetimeperformed, and hours are all new, but when I run rake db:migrate to push them to schema.rb, nothing happens.  It pauses and then gives me a new prompt, but the schema.rb file is not modified.

I have concluded that the migration is not going through for some reason, but have no idea why.  Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try .float instead of .decimal

Comment: If you just want to change the schema you can try a rake db:schema:dump. But if you already apply the migration then if you change the migration file, the db:migrate will not apply the changements. You can rollback and reapply the migrations but I'm not sure that is very good practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the changes are not getting picked up is because you are modifying an existing migration with version number less than what your `schema.rb` has.

If you want to add columns to existing table, you could create a new migration as:

```
rails g migrate add_project_user_performance_datetime_to_work
```

This will give you a file in `db/migrate/...add_project_user_performance_datetime_to_work.rb`.  Modify this file to define the columns here.

```
class AddProjectUserPerformanceDatetimeToWork < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :works, :project_id, :integer
    add_column :works, :user_id, :integer
    add_column :works, :datetimeperformed, :datetime
  end
end
```

Then running `rake db:migrate` should pick up this change.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice your migration file has a timestamp associated to it. This is how Rails keeps track of which migrations have already been run.

Old migrations won't get run when you re-run `rake db:migrate`. What you need to do is create a new migration with the changes that you wanted to do to the existing table and run `rake db:migrate`

If you run `rake db:migrate:status` it will show you which migration files have already been executed and which haven't. Make sure you don't change your old migration files unless you have a really good reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you've run the migration previously, it won't run again. Rails keeps track of the migrations that have been applied and will only run new ones when you `rake db:migrate`.

To check this, you can run `rake db:migrate:status` to list all migrations and their status.

Each time you want to make changes to the db generate a new migration, make the changes you need, and then run it:

```
rails g migration my_migration
```

You can also change existing migrations that have already been applied by rolling them back, as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-existing-migrations